# Add Component programmatically into specific node (boostrap modals)

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular

I'm developing an **Angular2** application and now I'm facing with **Bootstrap Modals**.

As you know, Modals work great only if you append them to the `body` node.
My application has a lot of modals and sometimes I use the same modal in different cases.

So I need to create modals dynamically and put them directly into the `body` element (and remove them once the dialog is closed). And I need to achieve this intent from **anywhere**.

For example, if one of my components needs to display a modal it should do something like:

```
var modal = new MyModal();
modal.show(myArgument); // append the html to the body
modal.onResult(result => consoe.log(result));
```

Is possible to do this using Angular 2?
I take a look to `ComponentResolver` and `ViewContainerRef` but is seems that they work only if the dynamic-component is inside the component's template but this is not possible obviously.

Thanks!

Comment: What about using https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap. I guess they have a modal component. If you don't want to use it directly you can check out the code to see how they're doing it.